# tapGesture is not working for labels

Tags: ios5, uigesturerecognizer

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openNewView:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openNewView:)];
[writeReview_view setTag:1];
[map_view setTag:2];
[writeReview_view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture1];
[map_view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture2];


    -(void)openNewView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recog1
     {

            NSLog( @"recog1.view.tag == %d",recog1.view.tag);
            if (recog1.view.tag==2)
            {
               [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mapsegue" sender:self];
            }
            else
            {
               [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginsegue" sender:self];
             }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable userInteractionEnabled on the label

```
label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```